# Change style of jQuery Dialog title bar when got/lost focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a simple page with two jQuery Dialogs with the functionality of changing their titlebar colour when each gets or losts focus. In other words, focused window has a different titlebar colour which makes it easier to differ which has focus.
I have this code:

```
$(function () {
  $(".window").dialog({
    focus: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

but I don't know how to detect in the **focus** event whether it it gets or losts focus.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/JqQA6/

I needed the same and this solution works.

Comment: simple yet elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try [focusin()](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Comment: Sounds good, does not work with my code (in fiddle at least) http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8NYV9/

Comment: It seems div element doesn't trigger any focus when clicked.Instead, I was able to get a result with click but I haven't been able to select jQ dialog's titlebar by its class.

This worked fine though. http://jsfiddle.net/8NYV9/2/
If only you can select the element you want to change its class, this should do the work for you I guess.

Comment: Funny, I deleted my comment with "Try changing to .click" ;)

Comment: There is a bug using focusin and focusout. All elements using this must have TabIndex set.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog `focus` event is only called on gaining focus.  Stock jQuery UI dialog boxes have no concept of losing focus.

A simple solution is to simply remove your `ui-state-error` class from *every* dialog in the `focus` handler and then add it to the one that's just received focus.

I've actually written a full-featured jQuery UI plugin which adds a `.blur` event to dialog boxes, and handles re-ordering stacked boxes whenever the topmost box is closed. I'll check if I'm allowed to publish it.